# Get permissions for an User in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

my purpose is to get permissions for a given user. In particular, I'd like to get whether he can create/delete users and groups in the Azure AD.
Is there a way to get this information using some Graph APIs or C# classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [List memberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api to get the information of the Azure AD user role, and then determine whether the user has the permission to create/delete users and groups based on the role.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/memberOf
```

You can try to use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So basically I have to set some permissions those permissions... Could you please tell me how to set them? Then, how could I determine the groups/roles which allow you to create users/groups? With another Graph API?

Comment: @usergn  You can control which permissions a user has by [assigning different roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal?context=/azure/active-directory/roles/context/ugr-context) to the user in the Azure portal. For example, if you want a user to have the permission to create groups, you can grant him the groups administrator role.

Comment: @usergn   Then obtain which roles the user has by calling `List memberOf` api, and determine which permissions the user has by the role. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#available-roles) describes the specific permissions granted to each role in Azure AD.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point and everything is ok. What I found useful to complete the turnaround is this Graph API: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions