# How to get currently logged in user's roles from azure ad?

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory

i'm implementing role based aad authentication in my react app . In aad app i have defined roles ,so how can i get roles of user being logged in to serve content based on their roles ?

Note : For authentication i'm using react-adal library . Any help is appreciated .

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work? Please provide us with a [mcve] and refer to [ask].

Comment: What role are you talking about? Is it an Azure AD role or an app role?

Comment: You can check the `roles` claim by parsing the id token to view the role of the logged-in user. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which role you are talking about. If you are talking about **appRoles**, then you need to customize the [user app role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#example-user-app-role) in the application manifest, and then [assign the role to the logged-in user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles).

Finally, you need to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain the access token, because this flow requires the user to log in, and then you can use [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) to parse the **id/access token** and view the `roles` claim.

[image]

[image]

If you are talking about **Azure AD roles**, as far as I know, you can get the role of the logged-in user by calling [List memberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) ms graph api. You can see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66045418/get-permissions-for-an-user-in-azure-ad/66046282#66046282).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf
```